# How can I escape shell arguments in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, escaping, applescript, arguments

Applescript does not seem to properly escape strings. What am I doing wrong?

Example:

```
set abc to "funky-!@#'#\"chars"
display dialog abc
display dialog quoted form of abc
```

Expected / Desired Output:

```
funky-!@#'#"chars
'funky-!@#\'#"chars'
```

Actual Output:

```
funky-!@#'#"chars
'funky-!@#'\''#"chars'
```

As you can see, it appears that in the actual output Applescript is adding and escaping an extra `'`

I would be OK with the end characters being either `'` or `"` and I would also be fine with both the single and double quotes being escaped - but it appears that only the single quotes are actually escaped.

Comment: Applescript does not play well with single quotes inside double quotes. If you change the string to `funky-!@#\"#\"chars` it works fine. I would consider this a bug, but there is no need to hold your breath for a fix form Apple. Maybe ask over here : http://macscripter.net/ , or I can ask.

Comment: Yes! That'd be great if you could ask. Thanks.

Comment: It *should* be like `'it'\''s` and not `'it\'s'`

Comment: @Lri - what / why? That does not seem to be properly escaped to me.

Comment: @cwd Try running `say 'funky\'chars'` in the shell. You get a PS2 prompt because there's an uneven number of single quotes.

Comment: @17510427541297 - why is your name showing up as a strange number now?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Backslashes aren't usually interpreted inside single quotes in shells.

> Enclosing characters in single quotation marks preserves the literal value of each character within the single quotation marks. A single quotation mark cannot occur within single quotation marks.
>
> A backslash cannot be used to escape a single quotation mark in a string that is set in single quotation marks. An embedded quotation mark can be created by writing, for example: 'a'\''b', which yields a'b.

However they are interpreted by echo in sh, which is the shell used by `do shell script`:

```
do shell script "echo " & quoted form of "\\t" --> "\t"
```

Unsetting `xpg_echo` makes it behave like the echo in bash:

```
do shell script "shopt -u xpg_echo; echo " & quoted form of "\\t" --> "\\t"
```

Often it's simpler to use HEREDOC redirection instead:

```
do shell script "rev <<< " & quoted form of "a\\tb" --> "b\\ta"
```

Answer (score 7):

Use "quoted form of". In general in applescript we are dealing with a "mac" style path so we would do something like this to pass it to the shell...

```
set theFile to choose file
set dirname to do shell script "dirname " & quoted form of POSIX path of theFile
```

Comment: I've updated the question because after testing this appears not to work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no extra `'` added in `'funky-!@#'''#"chars'`.

As already indicated by `17510427541297`, AppleScript's `quoted form of` idiom is meant for use in Unix shells, and strings in Unix shells get concatenated if they are placed directly next to each other.

AppleScript's `quoted form of abc` just does this: it creates a string enclosed by single quotes, but replaces every single quote `'` withing that string with `'''`.

This, in fact, creates three separate strings, but the three separate strings are subject to the following string concetanation mechanism in (most) Unix shells:

`"funky-!@#'#"chars"` becomes `'funky-!@#'` + `'` + `'#"chars'`

The resulting string is fit to get interpreted by Unix shells as a single literal string (without causing parameter expansion issues and the like).

```bash
# in Terminal.app
# note the escaping in: osascript -e '...'\''...'
quotedsrt="$(osascript -e '
set abc to "funky-!@#'\''#\"chars"
return quoted form of abc
')"

echo "$quotedsrt"                 # 'funky-!@#'\''#"chars'
eval echo "$quotedsrt"            # funky-!@#'#"chars
echo echo "$quotedsrt" | sh


# escaping mechanism for Bash shell
set +H
esc="'\''"
str="funky-!@#'#\"chars"
str="'${str//\'/${esc}}'"
set -H

echo "$str"                  # 'funky-!@#'\''#"chars'
eval echo "$str"             # funky-!@#'#"chars
echo echo "$str" | sh
```