# Using quotes in a AppleScript string

Tags: applescript

I am working with AppleScript and need to do this:

```
set TextToWrite to " #!/bin/bash cd "$( dirname "$0" )" java -server -Xmx4G -jar ./craftbukkit.jar" "
```

As you can see, the text I need to make into a string has quotes in it. How do I set

```
#!/bin/bash cd "$( dirname "$0" )" java -server -Xmx4G -jar ./craftbukkit.jar"
```

to an AppleScript string without the quotes messing it up?

Comment: My answer is [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10668503/990363). Your `bash` command could be simplified to `cd "${0%/*}" && java <params>`, BTW. No externals and a modicum of flow control.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To insert literal quotes into an Applescript string, you have to escape them, i.e.

```
set myString to "This is a \"quoted\" text."
```

AppleScript has the same convention as most languages, which is to use a backslash for escaping of special characters, of which there are only two: quotes and … backslash. See the [section “Special string characters” of the AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-BBCIAHJF).

Comment: Also note there are quite a few gotchas to the use of quotes in AppleScript strings if these are passed to the shell, most of them having to do with how the shell processes escaped and unescaped quotes. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138167/how-can-i-escape-shell-arguments-in-applescript) for some more details.

Answer (score 4):

The following syntax can also be used:

```
set aString to "quoted"
set myString2 to "This is a " & quoted form of aString & " text."
```

Comment: this gave me single quotes

Answer (score 0):

quoted form of (dirname as POSIX path)

Answer (score 0):

```
set x to "He said   \" Enter the matrix.\"   "display dialog x
```

Just copy this into applescript the easiest way to understand.

Comment: This question is 3 years old! How is your answer better than @kopischke's?

Answer (score -3):

Using quotes in applescript is quite easy you just need to make the line end and start in quotes

E.G

display dialog "hello world"

but when you decide to put a variable in the text you must use &

set my_name to "michael"

display dialog "hello" & my_name

thankyou

Comment: The question is related to using quotes _within_ a string (i.e. escaping them). This just creates a standard string.

Comment: Oh im sorry i didnt realize you wanted to get out of strings to do that all you must use is the simle "&" symbol and if using