# Why is AppName always JarRsrcLoader?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

When I do "Export Runnable Jar" from Eclipse, and run it from Terminal in OSX, the App-name (visible in menu) is always JarRsrcLoader.

I understand that this is because the MANIFEST.MF specifies that class as the startup class, and it in turn loads my main class.

Which method is the best to use if I want to have my main class name as the app's name?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue on my System (Java 8, Mac OS X 10.8).  I resolved it by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069315/swing-application-menu-name-not-displaying-correctly-in-java-1-8/26080591#26080591).  Specifically, I was able to run MyJar.jar from the command line using:

```
java -Xdock:name="AppNameInMenu" -jar MyJar.jar
```

This way, instead of the menu being displayed as JarRsrcLoader, it now displays as AppNameInMenu.

In addition, on a related issue, this jar can be converted to an .app following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kwdK6Dg1a_Y).  But, instead of:

```
"java -jar " & p & "/Contents/Java/MyJar.jar"
```

You can use:

```
"java -Xdock:name=\"AppNameInMenu\" -jar " & p & "/Contents/Java/MyJar.jar"
```

You need the backslashes when using quotes embedded in quotes when using AppleScript (per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667800/using-quotes-in-a-applescript-string/10668503#10668503))