# Escape quotes on VBA MacOS

Tags: excel, vba, shell, escaping, quotes

I would like to execute a shell script in Excel with VBA. However, I need to use quotes `"` inside of my command. To figure out how I can escape quotes in the function `MacScript` I simply try it with a simple command but I fail all the time.

So, here is a working example:

```
Function HTTPGet2() As String

HTTPGet2 = MacScript("do shell script ""echo 'hello' """)

End Function
```

Output: `hello`

But now I want to display `he"llo"`. Both of the following examples I've tried already and both of them failed..

Try 1:

```
Function HTTPGet2() As String

HTTPGet2 = MacScript("do shell script ""echo 'he""llo""' """)

End Function
```

Try 2:

```
Function HTTPGet2() As String

HTTPGet2 = MacScript("do shell script ""echo 'he"& Chr(34) &"llo"& Chr(34) &"' """)

End Function
```

Can you guys please explain me why it doesn't work and how to make it work? I'm using Excel 2019 and MacOs on `10.14.4 (18E226)`

At the end this is the command I want to execute:

```
xmllint --html -xpath 'string(//*[@id="AssetAllocationLongShortTable1"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1])' http://tools.morningstar.de/de/xray/default.aspx\?LanguageId\=de-DE\&PortfolioType\=2\&SecurityTokenList\=F000000EM3\]2\]0\]ETEXG$XETR\|F00000J8T2\]2\]0\]FODEU$$ALL\&values\=50.00\|50.00\&CurrencyId\=EUR\&from\=editholding
```

But this isn't working as well..:

```
Function HTTPGet2() As String

    HTTPGet2 = MacScript("do shell script "" xmllint --html -xpath 'string(//*[@id\""AssetAllocationLongShortTable1\""]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1])' http://tools.morningstar.de/de/xray/default.aspx\?LanguageId\=de-DE\&PortfolioType\=2\&SecurityTokenList\=F000000EM3\]2\]0\]ETEXG$XETR\|F00000J8T2\]2\]0\]FODEU$$ALL\&values\=50.00\|50.00\&CurrencyId\=EUR\&from\=editholding """)

End Function
```

Comment: Applescript has its own escaping requirements...  `MacScript("do shell script ""echo 'he\""llo\""' """)`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667800/using-quotes-in-a-applescript-string

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams! - I have added the final command I want to execute.. I have tried it with `\""` but somehow it isn't working.. do you know why?

Comment: Since backslash `\ ` acts to escape the next character you also need to escape any `\ ` in your command by doubling them up `\\ `

Comment: `MacScript("do shell script "" xmllint --html -xpath 'string(//*[@id\""AssetAllocationLongShortTable1\""]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1])' http://tools.morningstar.de/de/xray/default.aspx\\?LanguageId\\=de-DE\\&PortfolioType\\=2\\&SecurityTokenList\\=F000000EM3\\]2\\]0\\]ETEXG$XETR\\|F00000J8T2\\]2\\]0\\]FODEU$$ALL\\&values\\=50.00\\|50.00\\&CurrencyId\\=EUR\\&from\\=editholding """)
    ` - this is not working for me.. tried it with `\\`. Can you may give me an example?

Comment: Sorry I'm not on Mac so can't help with testing...

Comment: @TimWilliams Alright.. maybe passing the url as parameter works.. but I cannot insert the url here as parameter.. do you know how to do this? `HTTPGet2 = MacScript("do shell script "" xmllint --html -xpath 'string(//*[@id=\""hphdl\""])' ""url"" """)`

Comment: Sorry- I have no knowledge of macscript other than what I just Googled on escaping quotes  ;-)