# sed is misbehaving when replacing certain regular expressions

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I am trying to remove numbers - but only when they immediately follow periods. Similar replaces seem to work correctly, but not with periods.

I have tried the following which was given as a solution in another post:

```
echo "fr.r1.1.0" | sed s/\.[0-9][0-9]*/\./g
```

I get `fr....`. It seems that even though I escape the period it is matching arbitrary characters instead of only periods.

This expression seems to work for the previous example:

```
echo "fr.r1.1.0" | sed s/[[:punct:]][0-9][0-9]*/\./g
```

and gives me `fr.r1..` but then for

```
echo "ge.s1_1.0" | sed s/[[:punct:]][0-9][0-9]*/\./g
```

I get `ge.s1..` instead of `ge.s1_1.`

Comment: Your expected output is `fr.r1..`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do I need to quote in sed command lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18759459/608639), [Quoting special characters with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20427289/608639), etc.

Comment: yes, I want to preserve those codes.

Comment: (OT: `[0-9][0-9]*` can be shortened to `[0-9]\+`.)

Comment: @Biffen that'd be GNU sed only. With POSIX seds it'd be `\{1,\}` instead of `\+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to put the sed instructions between single quotes to avoid interpretation of some of the special characters by your shell:

```
echo "fr.r1.1.0" | sed 's/\.[0-9][0-9]*/\./g'
fr.r1..
```

Also you do not need to escape the dot in the replacement part (`.`) and `[0-9][0-9]*` can be simplified into `[0-9]\+` giving the simplified command:

```
echo "fr.r1.1.0" | sed 's/\.[0-9]\+/./g'
fr.r1..
```

Last but not least, as POSIX `[:punct:]` character class is defined as

> *punctuation (all graphic characters except letters and digits)*
>   https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions

it will also include underscore (and a lot of other stuff), therefore, if you want to limit your matches to `.` followed by digits you will need to explicitly use dot (escaped or via its ascii value)

Comment: Thanks very much, that did it. I think I was having trouble with \+ for the same reason.

Comment: @DougAI: You can also use `sed -E 's/\.[0-9]+/./g'` as well, where you do not need to escape the `+` since you are  using extended regex, if you don't activate this option you will need to escape it as well as parenthesis as well as curvy brackets! Have a look at: https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html