# Confusing Shell Quotation

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm not a newbie to shell, but still got confused with some not so complex quotation problems. I guess there must be something misunderstood.

```
a: echo 'Don\'t quote me // Don    quote me
b: echo Don'\t' quote me // Don    quote me
c: echo Don\t quote me   // Dont quote me
d: echo Don"\t" qoute me // Don    quote me
```

Above three quotations go quite against my intuition. Doesn't single quote `'...'` literally returns what is quoted? What I thought is..

For a: in single quoted `'Don\'`, `\` is nothing but a common character. So a) should be `Don\t quote me`.

For b: like a), `'\t'` suppressed the special meaning of `\t`, so I thought b) should be `Don\t quote me` too.

For c: I understand why c works, but don't understand the diff between a&b and c.

For d: no difference between `'` and `"`?

Probably I misunderstand how `shell` parse and execute the line of command..

**Problem solved by using `/bin/echo` instead of `(built-in)echo` on Mac. Latter one will interpret backslash.**

Comment: Are you supplying `-e` to `echo`?

Comment: I use Mac and there seems no `-e` option for `echo`. Do you mean `-n`?

Comment: Your `echo` seems to be interpreting backslash escape characters.

Comment: Your `echo` might be using an alias. Type `type echo` and see what you get?

Comment: @aubhava `echo is a shell builtin`

Comment: What shell are you using? The `bash` builtin `echo` does not process `\t` as a tab unless you use `-e`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per bash

1. the first one should return Don\t quote me
2. the second should return like the first one
3. the third should return Dont quote me
4. the last one should return Don\t qoute me

Why:

1. first one you scaped the don\t by putting it inside single quotes
2. you scaped only the \t
3. there is no scaping because \t means print the character after \ as is
4. double quote doesnt scape scape characters

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. So what makes thing look strange is my `echo` interprets backslash, after strings got `returned` as you described, right?

Comment: can you check the aliases maybe you are using echo with parameters

Comment: I use `/bin/echo` instead, now everything works like you said. Formerly I used `built-in echo`..

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding of shell quoting is correct, but it appears that `echo` on OSX is a shell builtin which interprets backslash escapes. This behavior can be turned off by executing `shopt -u xpg_echo`.

See here for more information:
[How can I escape shell arguments in AppleScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138167/how-can-i-escape-shell-arguments-in-applescript)